# DCHP Policies Server 2012R2

Tags: dhcp, windows-server-2012-r2

Tell me, please, is it possible to define a policy on the Windows Server 2012R2 DHCP which lease IP address to workstations based on the host name?
For example, there are a host OFF-CONTOSO. I want all hosts, starting with OFF issued certain parameters with DHCP.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about hostname but you can use the Ipconfig /setclassID command on your workstations to set a classID of OFF, then you can use DHCP to set Options and even an IP range just to clients that have the ClassID of OFF.